# Docusign combine Embedded view and custom envelope with pdf

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to combine the 2 API walkthrough examples but with the below code I get an authorization_invalid_request error.

Can anyone help me understand why that is?

Also I dont know if this is the optimal flow for it but what I want to accomplish is have the user sign a different document based on the pdf that is saved for that user in my local database and have the template dynamically created rather than have it predefined in docusign. Is there any better way of achieving that?

My code is:

```
<?php

class DocusignView {


    public static function getEmbeddedSignView($signerName, $templateId, $templateRoleName, $clientUserId)
    {        
        // Input your info:
    $email              = "***";              // your account email
    $password           = "***";                                   // your account password
    $integratorKey      = "***";  // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
    $recipientName      = '***';                    // provide a recipient (signer) name
    $templateId         = '***';       // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
    $templateRoleName   = 'Employee';                                   // use same role name that exists on the template in the console
    $clientUserId       = '1';                                          // to add an embedded recipient you must set their clientUserId property in addition to
                                                                            // the recipient name and email.  Whatever you set the clientUserId to you must use the same
                                                                            // value when requesting the signing URL
        // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);




    $envelopeId = DocusignView::requestSignByDoc($clientUserId);//$response["envelopeId"];

     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Get the Embedded Singing View 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
        "authenticationMethod" => "None", "email" => $email, 
        "userName" => $recipientName, "clientUserId" => $clientUserId
    );                                                                    

    $data_string = json_encode($data);    
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $url = $response["url"];

    //--- display results
    return $url; 
    }




    public static function requestSignByDoc($clientUserId){        

    // Input your info here:
    $email = "***";         // your account email
    $password = "***";      // your account password
    $integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
    $recipientName = "***";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
    $documentName = "***.pdf";      // copy document with same name into this directory!

    // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
//  echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, and one document and send
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // the following request body will place 1 signature tab on the document you supply, located
    // 100 pixels to the right and 100 pixels down from the top left of the document
    $data = array (
            "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
            "documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
            "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
                array(  "email" => $email,
                        "name" => $recipientName,
                        "recipientId"=> '1',
                        "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
                        "tabs" => array(
                            "signHereTabs" => array(
                                array(  "anchorString"            => "Signed .....................................................",
                                        "anchorXOffset"           => "0",
                                        "anchorYOffset"           => "1",
                                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent"=> "false",
                                        "anchorUnits"             => "inches" )
                            ))
                 ))
            ),
        "status" => "created"
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($data);  
    $temp = __DIR__.'/***.pdf';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($temp);

    $requestBody = "\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$data_string\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"$documentName\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$file_contents\r\n"
    ."--myboundary--\r\n"
    ."\r\n";

    // *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

        return $envelopeId;
    }
}
```

My JSON request:

```
"{
"returnUrl":"http:\/\/www.docusign.com\/devcenter",
"authenticationMethod":"None",
"email":"***",
"userName":"***",
"clientUserId":"1"
}"
```

My JSON response:

```
"{
   "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_REQUEST",
   "message": "The authorization request is malformed."
 }"
```

My authentication method is set to null but I had no problem running the embedded view example when I was not using the custom envelope(i.e. request sign by doc).

And heres an attempt using the API same problem with this one:

```
$docuSignClient         = new DocuSign_Client();
$docuService            = new DocuSign_ViewsService($docuSignClient);
$viewResource           = new DocuSign_ViewsResource($docuService);                
$signatureResource      = new DocuSign_RequestSignatureResource($docuService);

$temp = __DIR__.'/test.pdf';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($temp);
$document[]               = new DocuSign_Document('test.pdf', '1', $file_contents);

$recipient[]              = new DocuSign_Recipient('1', '1', 'Signer1', 'recipientsEmail@email.com', '1', 'signers');

$envelopeId  = $signatureResource->createEnvelopeFromDocument('TEST EMAIL SUBJECT', "PLease sign this", "created", $document, $recipient)->envelopeId;                
$returnUrl   = $request->getUri();
$url         = $viewResource->getRecipientView($returnUrl, $envelopeId, 'Signer1', 'recipientsEmail@email.com', '1');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you actually post the JSON requests/responses (with your username/password/integratorkey removed)?

Comment: @AndrewWilson Edited with the JSON request and response

Comment: Everything looks right from your code and your JSON. The only time I can reproduce your error is when I have invalid data in email/userName/clientUserId. I'd dig in there and make sure those variables are 100% correct

Comment: Also it looks like you're using `$email` for recipientEmail as well as sender login creds. Depending on your account settings, you may not be able to send to a different user name than what you have setup.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Thanks for the help Andrew. Could you possibly explain your last point as I am still a bit confused with where I should use which email and credentials. This is a simple dev account.

Comment: You have `$recipientName` setting a specific name for your signer. But you don't have `$recipientEmail` setting an email for that same signer. You're reusing the `$email` of the authenticated/sender account. During your testing and setup phase I'd use similar data to what you'd use in your production workflow. Your recipient may be the sender, but I'd still carry the email/name values in different variables so it covers all scenarios.

Comment: @AndrewWilson I think I found what the problem was. It was with the fact that upon creation of the envelope/template I use an email for the recipient. If I leave that blank and set the authentication method to None it works. Pretty strange.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Scratch that actually. It doesnt.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Tried using the API but again the same problem. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the bug was with the fact that the envelope is in a draft/created state and not sent! Makes sense but it took ages to figure out.

Comment: Ah yup! `"status" => "created"` would do it! The error messaging should probably be improved on.

Comment: @AndrewWilson Yeah the error message was not very helpful although to be fair page 167 of the rest API guide reads as follows: "This provides a URL to start the recipient view of the DocuSign UI for a sent envelope. This call
cannot be used to view draft envelopes, since those envelopes have not been sent"